# Maui - preventing jobs from running on the same node

Tags: qsub

I have a number of jobs that I would like to submit to a cluster. Each job slows down significantly when running on the same node as another but is not significantly affected by others running different types of calculations on the node.

Is it possible to specify such a constraint to `qsub` with a Moab (Maui) scheduler?

To be clearer, here's a description:

> nodes: node1, node2, node3 (each with 20 cores)
>
> my jobs: my1, my2, my3, my4  (each requesting 10 cores)
>
> other jobs: other1, other2 (each requesting 10 cores)

I'd like the following assignment (after submitting all jobs to the queue)

> Running:
>
> ```
> node1 <-- my1, other1
> node2 <-- my2, other2
> node3 <- my3
> ```
>
> Held:
>
> ```
> my4
> ```

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is by configuring a generic resource locked to each individual node, and then requesting it when submitting a more resource-intensive job.

Example configuration:

```
    NODECFG[node1] GRES=highdemand
    NODECFG[node2] GRES=highdemand
    NODECFG[node3] GRES=highdemand
```

Job submission:

```
$ qsub -l gres=highdemand -N my1 my.sh
```

This will restrict nodes to one "highdemand" job at a time, while still permitting other jobs to run on the remaining resources.